# How to change programatically (IronPython) the color for a set of Color Scheme Groupings within Spotfire?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

[image]

As you can see on the pic, I have 2 "Coloring scheme groupings". One is called 'red' and
one 'green'. I wish to chamge the colors for 'All valeues' for them to some different colors.

I wish to do it using IronPython script plugged to the button.

I would appreciate suggestions on which http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/ API objects represent this Color scheme groupings and what methods to use to make the change.

Answer (score 2):

I realize it's been a while since this was posted, but here's a solution.  It doesn't actually use the API objects, but I've found that when using Spotfire, it's important not to overlook workarounds, though I recognize this is a "brute force" solution, and does not allow you the dynamic methodology I'm sure would be preferable.

Create a string Document Property -- I'm calling it ColorSelected here.

For each color you want to add, you need to add a rule.

Click the "Add Rule" button.

Switch the Rule type to "Boolean expression"

Set the Value's expression to "If('${ColorSelected}' = 'a', 1, 0) = 1"

On the action control, add a script with the code:
Document.Properties["ColorSelected"] = 'a'

When you click the button, it will set all values to the code of this new rule.

You can add additional rules for new colors in both groupings, and adjust the button scripts following the same logic.